# ASP.net , how display an alert box from server side code?

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp:button onclick... What I would like to do is display a JS alert should a condition not be met. I'm wondering how can I call or create the simple JS function from server side code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "keyForScript", "alert('error!')", true);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx

Comment: Well he just puts this somewhere in his codebehind when a condition is met, so I thinks it answers his question.